# Culture specific Currency with DataFormatString

Tags: xaml, dataformat

I am using the Telerik Silverlight grid (XAML) and have a currency field which always needs to be showed with the $ symbol.

I use this to format the value as currency:  DataFormatString="{}{0:c}"

However, this uses the thread culture (as you would expect) - so if the client is in a different region it shows that currency formatter. I know I could use a converter and set the CultureInfo with String.Format, however, my question is: Can you do this in DataFormatString with XAML and no code behind?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DataFormatString="{}{0}$"
```

Comment: This doesn't work - the number has no format at all (ie. with C you get spaces every 000 and the correct currency decimal point. Also - if the value is blank it now shows a "$" - thanks though